# Upgrading nodejs on Ubuntu: How to fix broken pipe error?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, dpkg

Trying to upgrade nodejs on ubuntu 20.10.

Ran the official installation instructions:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Got the following error:

```
The following packages will be upgraded:
  nodejs
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/24.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 119 MB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 277425 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nodejs_14.15.4-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nodejs (14.15.4-deb-1nodesource1) over (12.18.2~dfsg-1ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_14.15.4-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/doc/nodejs/api/dgram.json.gz', which is also in package nodejs-doc 12.18.2~dfsg-1ubuntu2
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_14.15.4-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've looked at other StackOverflow answers recommending that I either try to uninstall nodejs-doc (the conflicting dependency) or to run the following command:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /usr/share/doc/nodejs/api/dgram.json.gz
```

Neither seemed to work. In the case of the above command, it said that the file needed to be a deb package - and anyway, I'm a little skeptical about that strategy as it could break my setup.

For attempting to removing nodejs-doc, I got the following output:

```
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nodejs : Depends: libnode72 (= 12.18.2~dfsg-1ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: nodejs-doc but it is not going to be installed
```

I've also tried running the recommended `apt --fix-broken install` but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Just a heads up: `curl ... | sudo bash -` is terrible from a security perspective. You run code as `root` without having a chance to review it. Unfortunately, this is becoming more and more common.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75943902/6194097

Answer (score 52):

All of this didn't work for me.

What worked was:

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq libnode-dev
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq libnode72:amd64
```

[via](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/issues/1157#issuecomment-1131212089)

Comment: `sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq libnode72:amd64` Worked for me

Comment: removing libnode-dev worked for me

Comment: Running just `sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq libnode-dev` then re-running the install worked for me, too (installing nodejs 20.x on ubuntu 22.x).

Comment: This worked for me while upgrading from version 12.x to 21.x.

Answer (score 19):

You need to enable the `universe` repository which provide the missing dependencies  [`libnode72 (= 12.18.2~dfsg-1ubuntu2)`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/libnode72) and [`nodejs-doc (12.18.2~dfsg-1ubuntu2)`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/nodejs-doc) in Ubuntu 20.10 :

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt install libnode72 nodejs-doc
```

`dpkg -i --force-overwrite` should point to the `.deb` file:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite  /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_14.15.4-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: follow you step, it's showing 
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_16.15.0-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb (--install):
 conflicting packages - not installing nodejs
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_16.15.0-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb

Answer (score 13):

Just delete nodejs-doc:

```
sudo apt remove nodejs-doc
```

Answer (score 8):

Other answers didn't work for me but I installed it successfully after trying these :

delete the new package source

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d 
sudo rm nodesource.list
```

update apt, fix the install, remove nodejs and the nodejs-doc packages

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt update
sudo apt remove nodejs
sudo apt remove nodejs-doc
```

Then install node & npm normally

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

[via](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/issues/1157#issuecomment-1131212089)

Comment: Only this worked. Also with 18.x.

Comment: Thankyou this is the most easy and accurate answer

Answer (score 7):

Run these commands:

```
sudo apt remove nodejs  
sudo apt remove nodejs-doc
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq libnode-dev
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq libnode72:amd64
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | sudo -E bash - && sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 5):

What you need to do is to remove the previous node version to avoid conflict

```
sudo apt remove nodejs
```

then, you can run:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | sudo -E bash -

sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Mind you,

> setup_18.x

can be anyone node version you want to install

Comment: This, plus "sudo apt autoremove" after uninstalling the old nodejs.

Answer (score 3):

For those that have accidentally installed NodeJS version 12 on Ubuntu 22. Be sure to execute

```
sudo apt autoremove nodejs
```

before installing the node 18 LTS

Answer (score 2):

I was tring to update to node from v12.x to v14.21.1, using:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x -o setup_14.sh
sudo sh ./setup_14.sh
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nodejs
```

And I had the same problem in the error, it seems that there are already a previous instillation of node packages that are not compatible anymore so

My Error message was

```
Unpacking nodejs (14.21.1-deb-1nodesource1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_14.21.1-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/node/common.gypi', which is also in package libnode-dev 12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_14.21.1-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

As you can see the error said that a file from `libnode-dev` could not be overwritten, so I removed the lib and tried again. So another different error poped up:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_14.21.1-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp', which is also in package libnode72:amd64 12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_14.21.1-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

As you can see the error said that a file from `libnode72:amd64` could not be overwritten, so I removed the lib and tried again. And worked

**Summarizing the solution**

```
sudo apt remove libnode-dev
sudo apt remove libnode72:amd64
sudo apt install nodejs
```

verifing if it worked:

```
node -v
```

```
v14.21.1
```

Comment: Basically a duplicate of [dirkk0’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/722477/23408).

Comment: This worked for me, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the Node.js installation is failing because there is a conflict with another package on your system (libnode72:amd64).

To resolve this conflict, you can try removing the libnode72:amd64 package and then installing Node.js again. Here are the steps you can follow:

Connect to your server using SSH.

Remove the libnode72:amd64 package:

```
sudo apt-get remove libnode72:amd64
```

Update the package list:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install Node.js:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

This will install the latest version of Node.js (16.x) from the official NodeSource repository.

Verify that Node.js is installed:

```
node -v
```

This should print the version number of Node.js installed on your system.

After following these steps, you should be able to use Node.js on your server. If you encounter any other errors, feel free to ask for further assistance.

Comment: This is what works presently

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me (Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS which already has a node 12.x from OS)

Remove the one coming in the error

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq libnode72:amd64
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | sudo -E bash - &&sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I simply needed to run `sudo apt autoremove` first. Nodejs had previously been installed by apt (which on U22 installs node v12!) and leftover packages were conflicting with the nodesource installer.

Answer (score -1):

Just Write

```
sudo apt purge nodejs

sudo apt autoremove

sudo apt install -y nodejs
```

Comment: Could you say something about why the user should run the commands you list and how it differs from what other answers suggest?